# How to add dynamic controls in proper way?

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have following code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {

            TextBlock Tb = new TextBlock();
            Tb.Text = k[3+i];
            Tb.Width = 205*((i<2)?1:0.5);
            Tb.Height = (stala*10)/3;
            Tb.Margin = margin;
            margin.Top += ((stala * 10) / 3);
            this.Str1.Children.Add(Tb);

        }
```

Textblocks are added but just for a second... when the animation stops, controls also dissapearing... Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Do you add it in a control like stackpanel or a grid ?

Comment: the animation code would be helpful

Comment: I've found something strange ... when i change margin it can be visible in upper(title) grid,where it dont disapear ... but str1 is lower grid ... i just dont get it .... how it possible that i wont disapear in upper grid but in lower is visible just for few secs.... any help pls?

Comment: About animation is standard animation when page apears but im sure animation its not the point

Comment: Can you please write down the animation So that we have a fair idea what you are talking about. And the specific place where this code is written I mean the method or the event where ever its written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you need a set of repeating controls at runtime that are of unknown quantity at designtime, the correct way is to use an itemscontrol or some control that inherits from itemscontrol like gridview and bind that itemscontrol to a property of value observablecollection. Then you manipulate the members of the observablecollection and the itemscontrol will create the corresponding controls for you according to its itemtemplate property.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
                    <AddDeleteThemeTransition />
                </StackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
            </StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

In addition, if you want animations, then on the itemscontrol's itemspanel you can set the childrentransitions with something from the animation library and you are good to go.

It sounds like binding may be new to you. You might want to review my primer on the topic here: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/10/xaml-binding-basics-101.html